# How to use composer packages embed/embed inside codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I am successfully installed embed/embed inside my project.
**Getting error Fatal error: Class 'Embed' not found**, anyone tell me how to fix this problem.

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {

    public function og_test()
    {
        //Load any url:
        $info = Embed::create('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP1xn5wHtxE');

        //Get content info

        $info->title; //The page title
        $info->description; //The page description
        $info->url; //The canonical url
        $info->type; //The page type (link, video, image, rich)
        $info->tags; //The page keywords (tags)

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you installed inside `application` folder or on `root`?

Comment: i am installed inside root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install your repository('composer require embed/embed') via composer on your project `root/home`, where you can find default `index.php`.

Go to `application>config>Config.php`.

Look for `$config['composer_autoload']`.

It will be set to `FALSE` in default, just change it to `TRUE`.

Use `use Embed\Embed;` in your controller.

Now try using it in your controller it should be accessible.

```
use Embed\Embed;
class Home extends MY_Controller {

    public function og_test()
    {
        //Load any url:
        $info = Embed::create('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP1xn5wHtxE');

        //Get content info

        echo $info->title; //The page title
        echo $info->description; //The page description
        echo $info->url; //The canonical url
        echo $info->type; //The page type (link, video, image, rich)
        echo $info->tags; //The page keywords (tags)

    }

}
```

Comment: Do let me know if you are still facing any issue.